# How to get last modified timestamp of an external file?

Tags: javascript

How to get last modified timestamp of an external file?

I'm trying to use using `xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified")`, and I am getting the pervious modified time, but not the recent modified timestamp.
e.g: `Fri, 02 Jun 2017 04:39:18 GMT` whereas I should get today's date.

Comment: `xhr.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified')` is the correct way of doing this. You should look around, your problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: the client can only go by what the server is sending

Comment: Minor format changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use get response as a `Blob`, pass `Blob` to `File` constructor to get `.lastModifiedDate` property value

```
fetch("/path/to/file")
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => {
  const file = new File([blob], blob.name);
  console.log(file.lastModifiedDate, file.lastModified);
});
```