# angular 6 get file last modified timestamp?

Tags: angular, file, date, timestamp

wonder how to get the file last mod timestamp via angular 6?

```
this.http.get('/folder/en.json')
.toPromise()
.then((response) => {
    console.log("json: " + JSON.stringify(resp));  
    console.log( response.headers.get('last-modified'));
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I seen some other code but its on angular 2, doesn't work on angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

If your json comes from backend you should get the timestamp from there.

For js solution try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362846/how-to-get-last-modified-timestamp-of-an-external-file).

Comment: If you are referring to an answer that can be found somewhere else, post it as a comment. If you can answer the question yourself (i.e. not copying an existing answer ;) you can post as an Answer of course.

Comment: I need 50 reputation for that :(